# How can I return the data I'm scraping when using beautifulsoup and concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, concurrent.futures

Trying to async scrape some recipes from nyt cooking and was following this blog: https://beckernick.github.io/faster-web-scraping-python/

It will print the results without a problem but for some reason my `return` does nothing here. I need to return the list. Any ideas?

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

MAX_THREADS = 30
urls = ['https://cooking.nytimes.com/search?q=&page={page_number}'.format(page_number=p) for p in range(1,5)]

# grab all of the recipe cards on each search page
def extract_recipe_urls(url):
    """returns a list of recipe urls"""
    recipe_cards = []
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    for rs in soup.find_all("article",{"class":"card recipe-card"}):
        recipe_cards.append(rs.find('a')['href'])
    
    print(recipe_cards)
    
    return recipe_cards

def async_scraping(scrape_function, urls):
    threads = min(MAX_THREADS, len(urls))
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        executor.map(scrape_function, urls)
```

Comment: you are not calling your function `extract_recipe_urls` anywhere . unless you call it , it `will not execute`, hence will not `return` too

Comment: I don't know how works `futures` but in `threading` or `multiprocessing.Pool` you can do `results = executor.map(...)`

Comment: maybe use [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) which uses async version of `requests`

Comment: ah sorry, I left out that line of code :facepalm:. I use this later on 
`recipe_urls = async_scraping(extract_recipe_urls, urls)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get

```
 results = executor.map(...)
```

and later you can use loop

```
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

or convert to list

```
all_items = list(results)
```

---

**BTW:** Because `results` is a `generator` so you can't use it two times in two `for`-loops (or in `for`-loop and `list()`) and then you have to first get all items as list `all_items = list(results)` and later use this list `all_items` in two `for`-loops.

---

Minimal working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import concurrent.futures
import time

# --- constants ---

MAX_THREADS = 30

# --- functions ---   

# grab all of the recipe cards on each search page
def extract_recipe_urls(url):
    """returns a list of recipe urls"""
    
    session = requests.Session()

    recipe_cards = []
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    for rs in soup.find_all("article",{"class":"card recipe-card"}):
        recipe_cards.append(rs.find('a')['href'])
    
    return recipe_cards

def async_scraping(scrape_function, urls):
    threads = min(MAX_THREADS, len(urls))
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        results = executor.map(scrape_function, urls)
        
    return results

# --- main ---

urls = ['https://cooking.nytimes.com/search?q=&page={page_number}'.format(page_number=p) for p in range(1,5)]
        
results = async_scraping(extract_recipe_urls, urls)

#all_items = list(results)

for item in results:
    print(item)
```

---

**BTW:** Every `extract_recipe_urls` gives you list so finally `results` is list of lists.

```
all_items = list(results)
print('len(all_items):', len(all_items))
      
for item in all_items:
    print('len(item):', len(item))
```

Results

```
len(all_items): 4
len(item): 48
len(item): 48
len(item): 48
len(item): 48
```

If you want all items as one flat list then you can use `list1.extend(list2)` or  `list1 + list2` which can be used with `sum(..., [])`

```
all_items = sum(all_items, [])
print('len(all_items):', len(all_items))
```

Result:

```
len(all_items): 192
```